# TAG JSON-data in Imacros

Tags: json, imacros

I'd like to extract Json-Data with Imacros.

E.g. like this

```
SET N EVAL("var obj = JSON.parse('{{!EXTRACT}}'); obj.list[0].firstname;")
```

However I keep having trouble with extracting them, since the JSON-Data is not displayed in any DIVs, classes, etc. and therefore not in the source code.

I tried
    `TAG POS=1 TYPE=SCRIPT ATTR=LANGUAGE:javascript&&TYPE:text/javascript EXTRACT=TXT`

but I cannot find the Data in any of the Javascripts, because they are not used in the document. But it is there - Firefox Networks Analytics can see it..

Also

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=application/json ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
```

doesn't work (error: #EANF#)

How can I adress it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If there are no JSON-data in the source code, what is the variable name which contains that object? (I mean `window.someJsonVariable`.)

Comment: The variable is called data and using the console I can adress it with e.g.

    `alert(Data[0].id);`
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this workaround and adjust it to your needs:

```
SET SA "(function() {var doc = window.document; var elt = doc.createElement('input'); elt.type = 'hidden'; elt.id = 'myJsonObj'; elt.value = JSON.stringify(window.Data); doc.body.appendChild(elt);})()"
URL GOTO=javascript:{{SA}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=ID:myJsonObj EXTRACT=TXT

SET SR "(function() {var doc = window.document; doc.body.removeChild(doc.getElementById('myJsonObj'));})()"
URL GOTO=javascript:{{SR}}
```